# Group by adjacent rows based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
id     col1    col2
---------------------
 1      35      A
 2      40      B
 3      39      B
 4      39      B
 5      39      B
 6      40      B
 7      39      B
 8      39      B
 9      40      B
10      40      C
11      35      C
```

How do I make it so that it has a result like this:

```
id     col1    col2
---------------------
 1      35      A
 2      40      B
 3      39      B
 6      40      B
 7      39      B
 9      40      B
10      40      C
11      35      C
```

I want to `group by` `col1` that has same value in adjacent rows while also has same group in `col2` (`col1` values in `id:9` and `id:10` couldn't be grouped because it has different `col2` value)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599599/group-by-adjacent-rows-based-on-two-columns/34599655#34599655

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key idea is to get a grouping identifier for the adjacent rows.  The question is:  what characteristic of the rows is constant for rows that should be grouped together?

Well, here is one: the number of previous rows (based on `id`) that have different values in either `col1` or `col2` is the same for all rows in a group.

You can turn this observation into a measure for each row (using a correlated subquery). The rest is just aggregation:

```sql
select min(id) as id, col1, col2, count(*) as NumInGroup
from (select t.*,
            (select count(*)
            from t t2
            where t2.id < t.id and (t2.col1 <> t.col1 or t2.col2 <> t.col2)
            ) as grp
    from t
    ) t
group by grp, col1, col2;
```

demo: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qybbksuqvJYEAfTK1QHzCe/0)

Note: This will work well-enough on small amounts of data, but it does not scale particularly well.

Comment: Great answer and fantastic explanation! I can sleep peacefully now, thanks!

Comment: Note if the col1 or other fields are `NULLABLE` then you have to do `AND (t2.col1 != t.col1 OR (t2.col1 IS NULL AND t.col1 IS NOT NULL) OR (t.col1 IS NULL AND t2.col1 IS NOT NULL))` to prevent rows with `col1 IS NULL` get ignored since `NULL`s being treat as the same value with adjacent rows.