# How to collapse adjacent rows, grouping by some column?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I want to get statistics from some chat by messages per user. But I want to group adjacent messages. If user writes 3 messages one by one it counts as one.
For example, I have these records:

```
id  user   message
 1   1      text1
 2   1      text2 
 3   2      text3
 4   3      text4
 5   1      text5
 6   2      text6
 7   2      text7
 8   3      text8
 9   1      text9
10   1      text10
11   1      text11
12   3      text12
```

I need to get this result:

```
user
  1
  2
  3
  1
  2
  3
  1
  3
```

I expect to get subquery results with collapsed messages and then run query with "group by" for getting all stats.

I tried to run

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY user ORDER BY id
```

but it groups all messages by one user:

```
id   user
 1    1
 3    2
 4    3
```

Comment: *"I want to group adjacent messages"* -- not quite a job for SQL. SQL works with sets, not with individual items, and a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is, by its very definition, an unordered collection of items. It can be done using [MySQL variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html), though.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599599/group-by-adjacent-rows-based-on-two-columns/34599655#34599655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. (although in practice I'd be tempted to solve this kind of problem in application code):

```
SELECT MAX(user) user
     , i
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user
            , CASE WHEN @prev = user THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=user
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY i;
```

or...

```
SELECT DISTINCT user, i
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user
            , CASE WHEN @prev = user THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=user
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x
 ORDER
    BY i;
```